# Nested ng-repeat Issue to open list of rows with in the row

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to open all the list of items at a time of their respective repeated row, here is plunker http://embed.plnkr.co/omBL2czm9fRBEVIeQUyD/
please help me out.

> Here is my object:

```
       $scope.names=[
          {no:'1', name:'Jani', country:'Norway',
                   cities:[{city:'A1'},city:'A2'},{city: 'A3'}]},
          {no:'2', name:'Hege',country:'Sweden', 
                   cities:[{city:'b1'},{city:'b2'}, {city: 'b3'}]},
          {no:'3', name:'Kai',country:'Denmark', 
                   cities:[{city:'c1'},{city:'c2'}, {city: 'c3'}]}];
```

> Here is my html :

```
 <table>
    <tbody ng-repeat="name in names">
        <tr >
            <td>
                {{name.no}}
            </td>
            <td>
            {{name.name}}
            </td>
            <td>{{name.country}}</td>
            <td>
            <button data-ng-click="isOpenPayablePayments[$index] = !isOpenPayablePayments[$index]; togglePayablePayments(name.no, $index)" >Paid</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-ng-show="isOpenPayablePayments[$index]">
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>City</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr data-ng-repeat="city in cities">
                                <td>{{city.city}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

> Call back on button click within the repeat

```
      var getCities = function (no) {
        for (i = 0; i <= $scope.names.length; i++) {
            if (no === $scope.names[i].no) {
                console.log($scope.names[i].cities);
                return $scope.names[i].cities;
            }
        };
    };

    $scope.togglePayablePayments = function (no, index) {
        $scope.cities = getCities(no);

    };
```

I want to open the nested list with respective row. plunkr explains the issue.

Comment: The rule on SO is to put everything related to your bug on your question. You can add a plunkr if you want. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve That way, if plnkr is closed, your question does not become directly useless for the others.

Answer (score -1):

The problem isn't clearly explained however i see that when i open a 2nd tree all the items of all tree are the same. No need of the $scope.cities, it's the source of your problem.

i just changed the 2nd ng-repeat :

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="city in cities">
    <td>{{city.city}}</td>
</tr>
```

to this :

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="city in name.cities">
      <td>{{city.city}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: have you checked the objects clearly, it is not my issue, my issue with same type of Objects I've in my application. I have prepared a plunkr with exact issue. the Objects are different

Comment: i have a different behaviour. On IE 9, it isn't showing any city. On chrome if i click on Jani it shows A1/A2/A3. If  i click on Hege. It show b1/b2/b3 under Hege but it shows b1/b2/b3 under Jani too. It may not be what you're asking but this is a bug :). What do you want ? open all subsets in the same time, open only one and close others ?

Comment: on button click open, if it is opened if i click again on the same button it has to close, which ever the row i open it has to show the exact row's data. if I open First one open and and then Second row it has to show their respective rows data.

Comment: Yes this is what i said, it doesn't show their respective row data, it shows the row datas off the last one clicked on every of them. And i posted a fix for that